# Using different Raster field when is not "Field" parameter for "input value raster" with arcpy.sa.ZonalHistogram

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, histogram, raster-attribute-table

I want to get the Histogram of a Raster using the "Value" field in the raster attribute table.

The "feature zone data" is a shapefile and the "Input Value Raster" a 32Bit signed integer raster with an attribute table like this:

| OBJECTID* | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20030056 | 555 |
| 1 | 34530056 | 666 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 113166 | 128071087 | 777 |

I am running something like:

```
watershed=r'myWatershed.shp'
myRaster=Raster(r'z:\xxx.gdb\someRaster')
arcpy.sa.ZonalHistogram(watershed, "ID", myRaster, output.dbf', '', "ZONES_AS_FIELDS")
```

...and the output looks like this:  (WRONG)

| Label | ID_111 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | ### |
| ... | ... |
| 256 | 0 |

Instead of a table with 256 rows it should have the 113166 different classes in the raster.

### Q//

- How I can use the "Value" field in the Raster attribute table instead of this default 256 "scale"?
- Is there any syntax to indicate the default field like myRaster$Value,  myRaster[:,"Value"] or something?

  arcpy.sa.ZonalHistogram(watershed, "ID", **myRaster[:,"Value"]**, output.dbf', '', "ZONES_AS_FIELDS")

Answer (score 0):

In case someone have the same problem, I didn't find the way to use the Raster field so I tabulate the areas instead.

`arcpy.sa.TabulateArea(myRaster, "Value", watershed, "ID", r'memory/tabArea', myRaster, "CLASSES_AS_FIELDS")`

The tabulate area, returns the area instead the number of pixels but allows to use a different raster field (arcpy.sa.TabulateArea(**myRaster, "RasterField"...**).